# Python - how to combine data frame by for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following data frame:

```py
   Tower    Floor   Unit
0   1       1.0      A
1   1       1.0      B
2   1       1.0      C
3   1       1.0      D
4   1       1.0      E
5   1       1.0      F
6   1       1.0      G
```

I would like to create the following dataframe from floor 1 to 10:

```py
   Tower    Floor   Unit
0   1       1.0      A
1   1       1.0      B
2   1       1.0      C
3   1       1.0      D
4   1       1.0      E
5   1       1.0      F
6   1       1.0      G
7   1       2.0      A
8   1       2.0      B
9   1       2.0      C
10  1       2.0      D
11  1       2.0      E
12  1       2.0      F
13  1       2.0      G
....
63  1       10.0     A
64  1       10.0     B
65  1       10.0     C
66  1       10.0     D
67  1       10.0     E
68  1       10.0     F
69  1       10.0     G
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is a very open quesiton and you have shown no attempt at getting this to work. There are a few ways you could do this. Maybe try some, and if you have problems getting it to work, you can look for/ask a question about the specific issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tower': 1,
    'Floor': 1.0,
    'Unit': list('ABCDEFG'),
})
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(10)])
df = df.reset_index()
df['Floor'] = df.index // 7 + 1.0
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 11):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({"Tower": 1, "Floor": i, "Unit": list("ABCDGEG")})])
```

This concatenates the DataFrames one after the other, outputting:

```py
In [9]: df
Out[9]:     Tower  Floor Unit
        0       1      1    A
        1       1      1    B
        2       1      1    C
        3       1      1    D
        4       1      1    G
        ..    ...    ...  ...
        65      1     10    C
        66      1     10    D
        67      1     10    G
        68      1     10    E
        69      1     10    G

        [70 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: how if i also want to create a bigger dataframe with tower value from 1 to 10?
should i use a double for loop to achieve this?